# Flutter can't load Url Clickup into Webview [iOS]

Tags: flutter, dart

**Below is the error message:**

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11601c2a0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync 
Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=14436, error: 
Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
```

**Below is my current code:**

I have used an `InAppWebView` as follows:

```
    InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest:
              URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://app.clickup.com/login')),
          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
            crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(javaScriptEnabled: true),
          ),
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            webView = controller;
          },
          
          onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) =>
              debugPrint(message.toString()),
        ),
```